# How does create/add in Entity Framework Core work?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

Example, there are two tables

```
"Item"
-Id (PK)
-Name

"ItemExtension"
-ItemId (PK)
-....
```

When you use the add statement

```
context.ItemExtension.Add(_theItemExtension);
```

Does Entity Framework Core manage the ID? i.e I don't need to assign `Item.Id` (PK) to `ItemExtension.ItemId` (FK) ? Or must I manually assign the PK ID to the FK ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to the Item

```
public abstract class ItemExtension
{
    [Required]
    public virtual Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

before you add the item extension to context you need set the item id:

```
_theItemExtension.ItemId = _theItem.Id;
context.Add(_theItemExtension);
context.SaveChanges();
```

or you can set the item:

```
_theItemExtension = _theItem;
context.Add(_theItemExtension);
context.SaveChanges();
```

or if the Item has a list of extensions you can add it to the list

```
_theItem.Extensions.Add(_theItemExtension);
context.Update(_theItem);
context.SaveChanges();
```

And you can add or update an item directly on the context and entity framework will figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the `KeyAttribute` and the key property is integer or have specified the `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute`, EF will make your key as database generated. Otherwise, you have to add the key manually.